# Connection to oracle database via nodeJS

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I'm trying to establish an Oracle connection using NodeJS but while trying to connect i am receiving below error.

```
Error:  Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in your PATH environment variable.
If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html
A Microsoft Visual Studio Redistributable suitable for your Oracle client library version must be available.

    at OracleDb.getConnection (C:\NodeCon\node_modules\oracledb\lib\oracledb.js:270:10)
    at C:\NodeCon\node_modules\oracledb\lib\util.js:180:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at OracleDb.getConnection (C:\NodeCon\node_modules\oracledb\lib\util.js:168:14)
    at C:\NodeCon\server.js:41:32
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\NodeCon\server.js:58:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14) {
  errorNum: 0,
  offset: 0
```

I've downloaded and installed 64 bit Oracle Client Library but still  below error appears.

Using Visual Studio Code v.1.36 as my editor.

NodeJS code i'm using is as below :

```
let connection;
var oracledb = require('oracledb');

(async function(){

    try{

        connection = await oracledb.getConnection({

            user: 'Username',
            password: 'Password',
            connectString: 'hostname:portname/servicename'
        });



        console.log("Successfully connected");
    } catch(err){

        console.log("NOT connected");
    }finally{

        if(connection){
            try{
                await connection.close();
            }catch(err){
                console.log("Errror");
            }
        }
    }
})()
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "I've downloaded and installed 64 bit Oracle Client Library but still below error appears." This is almost certainly where you did something wrong, but you gloss over it with no detail. We can only guess about the problem with the information you've given. FYI: full Oracle client installation is a pain in the neck. Instant client is much easier to work with.

Comment: HI @jpmc26,
Thanks for quick response, much appreciated.
If i'd to gloss the error i'm doing i wouldn't had asked it out here.
I understand there is something which i'm missing which i'm trying to ask out.
There is either a constriant with my Oracle Client or an issue with my network proxy which if someone could help me identify would be much appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: There are far too many possible causes that are consistent with the error you received. No one can name all the things you need to check. You need to learn the basics of how binaries are found and narrow down exactly what is happening yourself. SO is not designed for the kind of interactive debugging session that would be required to go through all the possibilities.

Comment: I'd suggest going through Oracle's node.js install documentation for your OS (much better written than most of their docs) and make sure you followed all the steps. I'm guessing you missed the one about setting the PATH variable, but it could be anything. http://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instructions

Comment: Thanks @kfinity i'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resolved by following code:

```
oracledb.getConnection({

            user: 'username',
            password: 'Password',
            connectString: 'hostname:portname/servicename'

            },

function(err, connection) {
            if (err) throw err;


         connection.execute(

        //Your database query here.


//below code if you want to fetch data from database and show it on terminal
 function(err,results){
                 var metaData = {};
                 var rows = {};
                 console.log("error")
                 if (err){
                     throw err
                      }
                      metaData.name1 = results.metaData[0].name;      
                      metaData.name2 = results.metaData[1].name;


                 rows.row1 = results.rows[0][0];
                 rows.row2 = results.rows[0][1];
                 rows.row3 = results.rows[0][2];
                 console.log(metaData.name1+" : "+rows.row1)
                 console.log(metaData.name2+" : "+rows.row2)

        console.log("Successfully connected");

         );

      }
```

And if you're connecting via VPN make sure to connect to the server first then run above.

Comment: thanks.. it works.. that getConnection and execute fuction must be callback